# PHP header() function code removed when saved in a drupal node(php filter)

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to include some header codes in a drupal node using PHP filter as its text filter in order to force download a zip file.

My header codes look like this(http://davidwalsh.name/php-force-download):

```
  header('Pragma: public');     // required
  header('Expires: 0');     // no cache
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
  header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate ('D, d M Y H:i:s', filemtime ($file_name)).' GMT');
  header('Cache-Control: private',false);
  header('Content-Type: '.$mime);
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file_name));  // provide file size
  header('Connection: close');
  readfile($file_name);     // push it out
```

But my problem is that, when I save the node, the header codes disappear.

Is there something is drupal that I need to set in order for the saving of the node to go through?

Comment: Please provide full code which you are using.

Comment: Do I understand this right, that you are adding this code as content to a field in the node?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use header when nothing else has been output to the browser.

By the time Drupal gets round to rendering the content of your node part of your theme template will already have been output so header will no longer work and result in a PHP error.

Also by putting code in a nodes body it is stored in the database making debugging and version control difficult if not impossible. Personally I think the PHP filter is a terrible mistake and should never had been included in Drupal. It will be removed from the core in D8.

You will save yourself a lot of headaches in the long run by putting that code in a custom module. Take a look at [this tutorial](https://drupal.org/node/361112)...

Answer (score 0):

As Felix mentioned, dropping custom code in nodes is generally bad practice, especially if you're going to have large custom application within Drupal.

However, if you're wanting to override HTTP headers that have already been set in PHP you can use [`header_remove()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header-remove.php) to do so. Placing that function call before your code will achieve what you want.